# Pip install commands don't work until they have exhausted all timeouts, after which they work normally

Tags: python, pip, conda, pypi

Earlier today my pip started exhibiting this very strange behavior where any pip install command timouts 5 times before the download starts. This is unaffected by the --default-timeout flag. For instance, doing pip install pandas I get

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(\<pip.\_vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff4b60badc0\>, 'Connection to pypi.cogtree.com timed out. (connect timeout=1.0)')': /cogtree/simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(\<pip.\_vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff4b60c7040\>, 'Connection to pypi.cogtree.com timed out. (connect timeout=1.0)')': /cogtree/simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(\<pip.\_vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff4b60c7250\>, 'Connection to pypi.cogtree.com timed out. (connect timeout=1.0)')': /cogtree/simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(\<pip.\_vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff4b60c7460\>, 'Connection to pypi.cogtree.com timed out. (connect timeout=1.0)')': /cogtree/simple/pandas/

Collecting pandas
Downloading pandas-1.4.1-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (11.4 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 11.4 MB 6.9 MB/s
```

We would get the same exact result with connect timeout=10
I'm on
pip 21.2.4,
Python 3.8.8,
macOS 11.5.1,
and this is happening inside of a anaconda 4.11.0 virtual env with only default conda packages installed.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling pip, and conda. I can ping pypi.org fine. I tried this only multiple different wifi. Closing and reopening the terminal did not affect it either.

Comment: looks like you'd ever configured pypi to another source. try `pip install -i https://pypi.python.org/simple yourpackage`

Comment: @LeiYang this doesn't change the behavior unfortunately. Still get 5 timeouts and then normal behavior.

Comment: do you mean package got successfully installed at last?

Comment: @LeiYang Yes. 1 go through all 5 timeout errors, and then pip installs the package

Comment: if i were you, i wouldn' bother or care the warning messages then.

Comment: Every pip install takes 10 minutes as a result of this behavior. In the best case. Imagine you are setting up and env with pip install-r requierements.txt, pip goes through this whole timeout procedure for every single step, every download. So if that requierements.txt had 20 modules, with the standard 15 sec timeout executing 5 times, thats 30 minutes.

Comment: try add `--verbose flag` and see there's anything useful?

Comment: edited to remove personal info:
 this added Using pip 22.0.4 from /Users/<user name>/miniconda3/envs/bio_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)  All else was as before without verbose flag.